# Fit to page in react-pdf

Tags: css, react-pdf

There is a control in the rendered `PDFViewer` component of `pdf-react` to fit to page: [image]

I would like to style so that the content is fit to page by default. I could not find anything to this end in the documentation. So, how do I do it?